# Can android bluetooth accessories force the device to launch an application?

Tags: android, bluetooth, accessory

I am wondering if a piece of hardware can be developed (probably over bluetooth for example) that could launch an existing android application on your device.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this kind of functionality.

Has anybody come across this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are `ACTION_DISCOVERY_[STARTED|FINISHED]` methods that you could register a broadcast receiver for. [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html)

To register the receiver, go into your project's AndroidManifest.xml and add the receiver tag and some permission tags:

```
    <application ...>

            <!-- Add your receiver class like so, and declare that you want to listen
                 for the DISCOVERY_FINISHED action -->
    <receiver android:name=".PUT_YOUR_CLASS_NAME_HERE(e.g. BluetoothReceiver)">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    </application>
    <!-- Add the permissions you might need here -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

you should then be able to create the BluetoothReceiver class and override the onReceive method.

Answer (score 1):

The theory behind this is the following:

- You should generate a `BroadcastIntent`
- This `BroadcastIntent` is received by a `BroadcastReceiver`
- The `BroadcastReceiver` launches an application.

I've never used Bluetooth with Android, but there should be a Broadcast when someone tries to connect to you. You could listen to that.